# Angular does not render html in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-ngcontent, ng-content

I code some `html` in my component like below. I add `span` with specific class in renew `innerHTML` of an element:

```
        nodes = this.getAllTextnodes(this.textarea.nativeElement);
        x1 = nodes[0].data.substring(0, this.characterLimit - 1);
        x2 = nodes[0].data.substring(this.characterLimit - 1, nodes[0].nodeValue.length);
        x3 = '';
        for (let i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++) {
          x3 += '<span class="highlighted-text">' + nodes[i].nodeValue + '</span>';
        }

        replaceContent = x1 + '<span class="highlighted-text">' + x2 + '</span>' + x3;
        this.textarea.nativeElement.innerHTML = replaceContent;
```

but when my code run, my class did not apply to span. I get below photo to make this sense better:

[image]

and problem is here that i don't have `_ngcontent_c10` in my `span` , but i don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Is it possible to create a demo on https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: You can use the /deep/ keyword in your css within your angular app. I do not know your css but something like should work `/deep/ .highlighted-text {background-color: red;}` - see https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: You can do what @J.Knabenschuh said, or change encapsulation of entire component to: @Component({
. . .
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

Comment: @J.Knabenschuh thank you. it works.

Comment: @J.Knabenschuh `/deep/` is deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, I know, see the link. I do not known alternative ways, exepcted the suggestion by @Slaven Tomac